# Can't instantiate class android.os.BatteryStats

Tags: android

I have some method

```
        String className = "android.os.BatteryStats";
        Class<?> c = (Class<?>) Class.forName(className);
        Constructor<?> constructor = c.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[0]);
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Object obj = constructor.newInstance(new Object[0]);
```

and when i try to get an instance of class, i get an error

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class android.os.BatteryStats
```

Why?
How i can get an instance of **android.os.BatteryStats**?

I use by Android 4.4.2

Thanks.

Comment: Because it is not meant to be instantiable! No public contructor, and it isn't part of the public API. And by the way, it's an abstract class, so not instantiable anyway: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7e11b16/core/java/android/os/BatteryStats.java

Comment: @Simon Marquis, thanks. "android.os.BatteryStats" class has inner "android.os.BatteryStats$Uid". How i can invoke some method of inner $Uid?

Comment: You can't, unless there is a public API to do so

Comment: For example - android.os.ServiceManager - http://jhshi.me/2014/04/02/get-package-usage-statistics-in-android/. Class "android.os.ServiceManager" hasn't public constructor too, but author got data from it.